# how to choose and sum data from excel table automatically

Tags: excel, vba, sum

I'm setting up an excel data table that i need to make a monthly statistics from it. how can i automatically choose a characteritic from the table and get all its values sumed up ?

This is a garage based data, that includes daily entries and the productivity of every technicien on a daily basis. What i'm asking for is, can i find a way to sort all 5 techniciens in a different table and get their productivity summed up automatically ?

here is the data table and an example for what i am trying to do.

```
n   Date    CLIENT  Date d'entrée     MO    Techniciens    HT€        Prestation


1   01/03/2019  YAYA    01/03/2019  30 900  FLORENT 30 900  Passage au banc


2   05/03/2019  DAVID   05/03/2019  30 000  LOBA    30 900  Passage au banc


3   07/03/2019  NAME    20/02/2019  60 000  YAPO    60 000  Ctrle injecteurs


4   08/03/2019  MATFORCE    01/03/2019  39 000  LOBA    42 151  Passage au banc
```

what i want is to have another table with the techniciens name in it and the sum of HT€

```
technicien  heures factures/mois

PRINCE  10 000

MOUSSA  

ETIBOIS
```

Comment: Easiest way might be a pivot table.  You could also use the `SUMIFS()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Select Data
2. Insert -> Pivot Table

   [image]
3. Set `Technicians` as Rows and `Sum of HT` as Values

   [image]

   > *Source data was slightly altered to better illustrate the answer*

Comment: Thank you, as i don't have a wide knowledge in excel, the pivot table really solved my problems. but now i have a new problem as when i try to insert a chronological date bar ( to filter the infos by date) i get an alert telling me there is no date format cells in the table. any help ?

Comment: Create a separate question please

Answer (score 0):

Like @Marc in the comment to the question, I would suggest SUMIF(), SUMIFS() or Pivot Tables.

Pivot Tables are the easiest as they can SUM by multiple criteria without a lot of programming.  But they only do one thing at a time so SUM and AVERAGE need to be done separately.

SUMIF(range,criteria, sumrange) will return the sum of all of the cells in sumrange that are in the same row where the value in the range meets the criteria for example:

`=SUMIF(A1:A999,="Charlie",B1:B999)`

Where A1:A999 has the technicians' names, B1:B999 has their billing amounts

SUMIFS() is similar but allows multiple selection criteria.